# Why does the java regex "Look-behind group" need an obvious maximum length?

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I know that java regex "Look-behinbd group need an obvious maximum length.
Therefore, the following regex won't be compiled correctly in java:

```
"(?<=abc.*)(abc)"  "(?<=abc.*?)(abc)"  "(?<=abc.*+)(abc)"
"(?<=abc.+)(abc)"  "(?<=abc.+?)(abc)"  "(?<=abc.++)(abc)"
"(?<=\1)(abc)"
```

Normally, you need to do the following changes:

```
"(?<=abc.{0,30})(abc)"
"(?<=abc.{1,30})(abc)"
```

It seems that "Look-behind group" can't contain the catched group (e.g.: `(?<=\1)(abc)`), while "Look-ahead gourp" can contain (e.g.: `(abc)(?=\1)`).
Maybe, Java regex think the catched group doesn't have an obvious maximum length.
I don't know how to solve this problem to make java "Look-behind group" to contain the catched group. (I don't know how to set the obvious maximum length for catched group).

Meanwhile, I'm a little bit curious, since every input string for Java-Regex parsing, is a fixed-length string, if user doesn't set an obvious maximum length for "Look-behind group", why Java-Regex can't use the input string's length as its maximum length value defaultly.

Does anyone help me on my puzzle? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The answer is simple, you can't. As you notice it the Java regex engine doesn't allow backreferences in lookbehinds since the length of the backreference if considered as "not obvious".

Comment: "if user doesn't set an obvious maximum length for "Look-behind group", why Java-Regex can't use the input string's length as its maximum length value by default?" Because the expression is compiled once, and them applied to strings that could have different lengths.

Comment: However, Java has in several cases a strange behaviour with his "limited variable length", for example something like `(?<=a+)bcd` will work and something like `(?<=(?:ab)+)cd` will not.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1132-rematchgroup-udf-to-return-only-specified-group-in-regex-pattern.htm.  If nothing else, it hints at why certain things aren't allowed.  I'm guessing that it *could* be implemented but would be quite difficult and not worth the effort.  (Doing it right would probably involve constructing a mirror-image regex.)  Also, Unicode characters U+10000 and up may cause a problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenligh Yes, the expression is compiled once, however, in every 'matcher' operation, it could set the maximum length using the input string. On the other hand, I found, if I simple comment this statement "if (info.maxValid == false) { throw error("Look-behind group does not have " + "an obvious maximum length");}" in java's pattern class implementation, then all the above regex could be compiled & obtain the correct result. (Except the backreference support).

Comment: Meanwhile, maybe it's difficult implemented in java's regex mechanism. I want to konw, whether this look-behind behaviour is common to other regex tools, or any other regex tools could solve this kind of limitation. Thanks a lot.